# Adding attributes to SpatVect: Error in .local(x, ...): unused argument

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I keep getting the error Error in .local(x, ...): unused argument when using vect() to create a spatvect with attributes. When I'm not trying to put in the attributes it works fine. I  can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
long_lat <- data.frame(lon = c(18.5,18.5,18.5,18.6,18.6), lat = c(-34, -33.9, -33.6,-33.6,-34))

colnames(long_lat) <- c("lon", "lat")

atts <- data.frame(imi = c(123, 0.4, 706,21,9)

#works fine
pts_jan <- vect(long_lat,  crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

#error
pts_jan <- vect(long_lat,  atts = atts, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

> Error in .local(x, ...) :
> unused argument (atts = list(c(123, 0.4, 706, 21, 9)))

Comment: See the documentation (https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/vect.html). The data.frame method does not have an `atts` argument. Only the matrix method has that.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I was trying to use the code for the matrix method rather than the data.frame method. All works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

You can cbind the attribute data frame with long_lat data frame, then convert it to spatvect like

```
library(terra)

long_lat <- data.frame(lon = c(18.5,18.5,18.5,18.6,18.6), 
                       lat = c(-34, -33.9, -33.6,-33.6,-34))

atts <- data.frame(imi = c(123, 0.4, 706, 21, 9))

#Add the attribute data.frame to long_lat data.frame
long_lat <- cbind.data.frame(long_lat, atts)

#works fine
pts_jan <- vect(long_lat,  crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
pts_jan 

#> class       : SpatVector 
#> geometry    : points 
#> dimensions  : 5, 2  (geometries, attributes)
#> extent      : 18.5, 18.6, -34, -33.6  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> names       :    id   imi
#> type        : <int> <num>
#> values      :     1   123
#>                   2   0.4
#>                   3   706
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example data

```
library(terra)
long_lat <- data.frame(lon = c(18.5,18.5,18.5,18.6,18.6), 
                       lat = c(-34, -33.9, -33.6,-33.6,-34))
atts <- data.frame(imi = c(123, 0.4, 706,21,9))
```

Here are four ways to create a SpatVector with these coordinates and attributes

```
#1 
pts <- vect(as.matrix(long_lat), atts=atts, crs="+proj=longlat")

#2
pts <- vect(cbind(long_lat, atts), crs="+proj=longlat")

#3
pts <- vect(long_lat,  crs="+proj=longlat")
pts <- cbind(pts, atts)

#4
pts <- vect(long_lat,  crs="+proj=longlat")
values(pts) <- atts
```